# IP Banned from my own Website

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, ip-address

So recently, I added a php script that had to refresh the page a lot. This apparently caused my website to think that I was DDoSing it, and it automatically ip banned me and a bunch of friends that were using it with me. I can access my site right now with a vpn, so I was wondering, how do I remove the IP ban from the firewall?

I am using a paid shared hosting service, so I don't have root access to the server. I have access to the cpanel and all the tools that come with that. I'm thinking it isn't possible, but hopefully you guys have other ideas.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to check into sockets, like NodeJS. That might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely something you can do yourself on shared hosting. If you and your friends were banned for a perceived DoS/DDoS, then the ban would have to be applied at the firewall level or the router to stop future requests from consuming server connections. So you'll need to talk to your web host about unbanning your IP address and how to prevent a future repeat of this incident.

Answer (score 0):

I've been here, it's worth checking with your home internet connection provider to see if you can get a new IP address.

I use Virgin Media in the UK, as they provide dynamic IP's (leased in such a way that you have the same IP for months) you can reset your router and modem in such a way that it will pick up a new IP from their pool.